# Finding a suitable $N$ (convergent series).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm studying for an exam in introductory real analysis, and there is a practice question that goes as follows:

> Suppose that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges.
>
> a) Show that given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}<\epsilon$.
>
> b) For $a_{n}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ you know that the series converges. For $\epsilon=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{11}}$, find a suitable $N$.

I've done (a) and my result agrees with the worked solution given by our professor for revision.

I'm having difficulty understanding the answer for (b), however.

So, for (b) I started by computing
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=1.$$
I then was trying to fiddle with partial sums in order to find a suitable $N$, but I quickly became confused and lost.

The solution gives the following line:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=1,\:\text{ and }\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}.\tag{$\star$}$$
This line, after the "and", goes way over my head, and I'm worried I'm missing something simple.

Would somebody please be kind enough to explain what is going on after the "and" in $(\star)$? Sorry if this is a silly question, but I don't see how multiplying the series by the ($N-1$)th term gives us the sum from $N$ to $\infty$.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} a_k = \dfrac{1}{2^N} + \dfrac{1}{2^{N+1}} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{2^n}+\cdots = \dfrac{1}{2^{N-1}}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2^2} +\cdots +\dfrac{1}{2^n}+\cdots \right)=\dfrac{1}{2^{N-1}}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \dfrac{1}{2^{N-1}} < \epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2^{11}}\Rightarrow N -1 > 11\Rightarrow N > 12 \Rightarrow N = 13$ is the smallest $N$ you can have.

Comment: Thanks to you both @YvesDaoust. In short, I had a brain-fart. I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 2):

That's thanks to the identity

$$a_n=\frac1{2^{n-1}}a_1$$

implying

$$a_{n+k}=\frac1{2^{n-1}}a_{1+k}.$$

---

If you are familiar with geometric series, you can also directly compute

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}=\frac{\frac12-\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that $\,\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} = 1$.
Divide both sides of equation by $2$, get $\,\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \dfrac12$.
But $\,\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}}$ which is the sum of all terms in the series except for the first one!
Thus

\begin{align}
%\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}} &= \dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac18 + \dots = 1
%&\implies&&
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} &=
\left(\dfrac12 + \dfrac14  + \dots + \dfrac1{2^{N-1}} + \dfrac1{2^{N}} + \dfrac1{2^{N+1}} + \dots \right) - \left( \dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dots + \dfrac1{2^{N-1}}\right)
\\ &=
\dfrac1{2^{N}} + \dfrac1{2^{N+1}} + \dots
=%\\ &=
\dfrac1{2^{N-1}} \left(\dfrac12 + \dfrac1{2^{2}} + \dots\right)
=%\\ &=
\dfrac1{2^{N-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}
\end{align}

Thus we have shown that
\begin{align}
\bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} = \dfrac1{2^{N-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}
}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. Another clear answer. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Oldmate My pleasure :-)